# Flyway: Unable to determine URL for classpath location

Tags: sql, flyway

I am using flyway for migration of my SQL scripts. I have configured the flyway configuration file to point to the /tmp/sql directory where I have kept the migration .sql scripts.

Now when I am running the flyway it is giving me the below error:

```
ERROR: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:tmp/sql"/>
ERROR: Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: tmp/sql"/> (ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@2da679b7)
ERROR: Occured in org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner.getLocationUrlsForPath() at line 192
```

Now If I let the property flyway.locations unchanged and keep my sql migration scripts in filesystem:Flyway-INSTALL-DIR/sql it is working fine.

Could anyone please let me know what could be the issue?

I want to keep the sql migration scripts in a separate location and try migration from there.

Thanks,
Manish Joshi

Answer (score 2):

Make sure flyway.locations is set to filesystem:/tmp/sql

Comment: Hi Axel, Even then I am getting the below error:    ERROR: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: filesystem:/tmp/sql"/>
    ERROR: Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid filesystem path: /tmp/sql"/>
    ERROR: Occured in org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.filesystem.FileSystemScanner.scanForResources() at line 48

Comment: The path /tmp/sql do exists and has the following contents:[root@NewVoE6-osm01 flyway-3.0]# ls -ltr /tmp/sql
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  76 Dec  8 17:49 V4__manish.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  79 Dec  8 17:49 V3__Create_employee_table.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 270 Dec  8 17:49 V2__Add_People.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  79 Dec  8 17:49 V1__Create_person_table.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Dec  8 17:49 put-your-sql-migrations-here.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12 Dec  8 17:55 V5__hello.sql

Comment: Retry with 3.1 and add some debug output with -X to see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add at least one file to src/main/resources/db/migration and you should be good to go. Maven sometimes doesn't copy the directory to target if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also try these if above doesn't help?

```
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

or

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

or

and ensure the paths you're using really exist: ie I had a problem where I use db/migrations but real path was db/migration. Quite silly, but adding it here as it may save someone else's same time waste.